# Why when view returns a list of objects from db html file didn't pick the value

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

```
def index(request):
    context = get_all_tasks()
    return render(request, 'sentixplorerapp/index.html',context)
```

above is my view function when I return this to below html code snippet it return  the accepted outcome.

```
{% extends 'sentixplorerapp/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<table border="1" style="width: 80%;" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Task Name</th>
            <th>File Path</th>
            <th>Result</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for task in tasks %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ task.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ task.taskName }}</td>
            <td>{{ task.filepath }}</td>
            <td>{{ task.result }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        <!-- You can add more rows as needed -->
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

but when I change my view function as below It didn't get any values to html view. Can you help me to understand why?

```
def index(request):
    context = {'tasks': get_all_tasks()}
    return render(request, 'sentixplorerapp/index.html',context)
```

I'm expecting to get table data that return from get_all_task() view in html when it look like this,

```
def index(request):
    context = {'tasks': get_all_tasks()}
    return render(request, 'sentixplorerapp/index.html',context)
```

Comment: Paste this function `get_all_tasks`, what does it return ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I’m assuming your get_all_tasks() function isn’t actually getting called once the context dictionary is inside the template. In your first view example the function is assigned to context so it is called.

Try calling your function, assigning the value to a variable then sticking it in the dictionary.

This could possibly work:

‘’’python

```
def index(request):
    all_tasks = get_all_tasks()
    context = {'tasks': all_tasks}
    return render(request, 'sentixplorerapp/index.html',context)
```

‘’’

Answer (score 0):

I'm also bit new to django. But i usually declare context as an empty dictionary at the top of the function.

```
def index(request):
    context = dict()
    context['tasks']=get_all_tasks()
    return render(request, 'sentixplorerapp/index.html',context)
```